# Bootstrap4: is there a way to move a div into another div using media queries and CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I know there is a first/last utility in BS4, but my situation calls for moving an element to and from a totally different part of the page.

To illustrate what im trying to do, say i have the following

```
<div id='area1'>
   <div id='myElement'> My element </div>
</div>

<div id='area2'>

</div>
```

The goal is for `#myElement` to move into `#area2` and back responsively

Is there a way to do this just by CSS rules? And if not, how does one achieve this in as little JS as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I'm not clear how you want? If I understand your question it's very much possible using `data-*` `attribute`. Like `data-title`, `data-description`, `data-label` etc.

I think your content is dynamic. so your `HTML` will like this.

```
<div id='area1'>
   <div id='myElement'> My element </div>
</div>

<div data-area1element="My element" id='area2'>

</div>
```

Above `HTML` work without css for desktop mode even for mobile. Some reason you want to show `id="myElement"` content will show in `id="area2"` if browser with less than or equal to `767px` and `id="myElement"` will hidden. You have insert `id="myElement"` data in `data-area1element=""` attribute.

**Here is the CSS**

```
#myElement{
    color: green;
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
    #myElement{
        display: none;
    }
    #area2{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 2px solid red;
    }
    #area2:before{
        content: attr(data-area1element);
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
#myElement{
  color: green;
}

@media (max-width: 767px){
    #myElement{
        display: none;
    }
    #area2{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 2px solid red;
    }
    #area2:before{
        color: blue;
        content: attr(data-area1element);
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='area1'>
   <div id='myElement'> My element </div>
</div>

<div data-area1element="My element" id='area2'>

</div>
```

I'm try to solve it using CSS. I hope it will help you.

**After comments Try jQuery**

Using only `CSS` it's not possible. It need `JS` solution. Below is my code I try to solve that way. It will create duplicate element in smaller window.

```
<div class="container py-4">
  <div class="card p-3 mb-3">
    <h1 class="text-center my-4">Desktop Form</h1>
    <div id="desktopFrom" class="d-none d-lg-block">
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Your Name</label>
          <input placeholder="Your Name" type="text" name="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <buton type="submit" role="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send Form</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Desktop Card -->
  <!-- Mobile Card -->
  <div class="card p-3 mb-3">
    <h1 class="text-center my-4">Mobile Form</h1>
    <div id="mobileFrom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Above `HTML` using Bootstrap@4.

```
$(function(){
  var desktopForm = $('#desktopFrom').html();
  $(window).on('load resize', function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 991) {
        $("#mobileFrom").html(desktopForm);
    } else {
      $("#mobileFrom").empty();
    }
  });
});
```

> Custom `jQuery` Script.

Here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/rahulmoral/pen/ZEbJRVK). Try it if work for you!

Comment: i see what you did here.. good idea.. it's indeed one of the possible solutions for simple content, but what im trying to move around is a search bar with search field, etc.. I think it's a bit complicated code to be stored in data- attribute, dont you think?

Comment: @BrownChiLD I add `jQuery` solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle it with `css`

```css
#area1{
 width:300px ;
     height:300px ;
     
     background:blue;
}

#area2{
 width:300px ;
     height:300px ;
     
     background:#7100ff;
}
.element{
 width:100px ;
     height:100px ;
background:red;
}
#myElement1{
display: block;

 
}
#myElement2{
  display: none;
  
  
  }

@media only screen and (max-width: 415px) {
#myElement1{
display: none;
}
#myElement2{
  display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='area1'>
   <div id='myElement1'class="element"> My element </div>
</div>

<div id='area2'>
  <div id='myElement2' class="element"> My element </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip... but this solution requires me to duplicate things in each area i want the element to appear in. I cannot have duplicates, however. It must be the original element that moves around

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what are you doing. A very quick fix would be to add #myElement in #area2 and give it a class d-none. It's up to you when you are going to call it (depends on your breaking point).
Try something like this:

```
<div id='area1'>
 <div id='myElement' class="d-none d-md-block"> My element </div>
</div>
<div id='area2'>
 <div id='myElement'class="d-block d-md-none"> My element </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wouldl've been fine but this means i have to create a duplicate and that's not possible in my case